# How to load an ADF mid-app while Tango is running? (How to restart tango service)

Tags: google-project-tango

I'm trying to load an ADF while the Tango is running. So, I call InitProviders with the UDI of the ADF I want. And although the call seems to work, there's no real way to tell if it did--the Tango's pose doesn't seem to change which leads me to believe it's not updating the Tango.  Do I have to restart the Tango service?  And if so--how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a way to change the ADF on the fly using the C API. But the only way that I found to that in Unity is restarting the service, as well. 
To do that you have to call the method  `Shutdown()` of the instance of  `TangoApplication`. And start the services again.

Comment: Thank you!  I hope I can submit in time--been struggling with this for a week now.